# React Router in different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

So I have two components at the moment App.js and MainNav.js. My goal here is to have App.js contain all of the routing information and have MainNav.js contain the navigation.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as ReadableAPI from './Utils/ReadableAPI';
import { Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import {addPost} from "./Actions/Posts";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import MainNav from "./Components/MainNav";

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount = () => {
        const { store } = this.props;
        console.log(store.getState());
    }
    addPost = () => {
        let timestamp = Date.now();
        this.props.store.dispatch(addPost({
            id: 'fdafsf',
            timestamp: timestamp,
            body: 'this is the body',
            author: 'this is the title',
            category: 'category',
            title: 'this is the title'
        }))
    }
    render() {
        const { category, posts } = this.props;
        console.log(category);
        return (
          <div className="App">
              <Route exact path={"/"} render={() => (
                  <div>
                      <MainNav categories={category} active={"all"}/>
                  </div>
              )}/>
              <Route path={"/react"} render={() => (
                  <div>
                    <MainNav categories={category} active={"react"}/>
                  </div>
              )}/>
              <Route path={"/redux"} render={() => (
                  <div>
                    <MainNav categories={category} active={"redux"}/>

                  </div>
              )}/>
              <Route path={"/udacity"} render={() => (
                  <div>
                    <MainNav categories={category} active={"udacity"}/>
                  </div>
              )}/>
          </div>
        );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({posts, category}) {
    return {
        posts: posts,
        category: category
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(App))
// export default App;
```

MainNav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class MainNav extends Component{
    static propTypes = {
        categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        active: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        const { categories, active } = this.props;
        const currentTab = active;
        return (

            <div className={"main-nav-container"}>
                <ul className={"main-nav-list"}>
                    <li className={"main-nav-list-item " + (currentTab === 'all' ? 'active':'')}>
                        <Link
                            to={"/"}
                        >
                            <div className={"category"}>
                                All
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    {categories.map( (category) => (
                        <li className={"main-nav-list-item " + (currentTab === category.name ? 'active':'')} key={category.path}>
                            <Link
                                to={"/" + category.path}
                            >
                                <div className={"category"}>
                                    {category.name}
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MainNav
```

The issue being that the link components are indeed changing the URL but do not seem to be updating the props within MainNav (I need those to update in order to change which nav item is considered active). Is this the right method or do I need to have all of this code repeated within App.js?

edit:

As requested here is my index.js file which is my top level file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import reducer from './Reducers'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as ReadableAPI from './Utils/ReadableAPI';
import {addInitialStatePost} from "./Actions/Posts";
import {addInitialStateCategories} from "./Actions/Categories";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__  || compose;

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(logger)
    )
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}>
        <App store={store}/>
    </Provider></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')

);
registerServiceWorker();

//set up the initial state of the app
ReadableAPI.getAllPosts().then(res => res.forEach((p) => {
    store.dispatch(addInitialStatePost({
        id: p.id,
        author: p.author,
        body: p.body,
        category: p.category,
        commentCount: p.commentCount,
        deleted: p.deleted,
        timestamp: p.timestamp,
        title: p.title,
        voteScore: p.voteScore
    }))
}));

ReadableAPI.getCategories().then(res => res.forEach((c) => {
    store.dispatch(addInitialStateCategories({
        name: c.name,
        path: c.path
    }))
}));
```

Comment: Your routes are not in a <Router> tag. For instance I have this in my "Root" level of my app:

<Provider store={store}>
    <div>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes}/>
    </div>
</Provider>

Comment: I do have one file above this index.js where I do something like so: ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}>
        <App store={store}/>
    </Provider></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')

);   

is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you post the top level file as well then please, and anything else that may help?

Comment: I think you will need your router within your provider tag, rather than your provider tag within your browserrouter tag?

Comment: You're provider has to wrap your browser router component I believe.

Comment: great minds think alike, that works perfectly.